# How can I input special characters when using msgBox and how can I edit the text that pops out in the OK button?

Tags: batch-file, special-characters

I recently learned how to use *msgBox* when making a simple *.bat* file. As someone stated [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1225455/how-to-make-an-error-message-in-a-batch-script-if-the-target-isnt-present/1225508?newreg=b1253e36640745c4aba891b7544e95c4), it's very simple. The code I have is the same as the top answer on that link, so:

```
IF NOT DEFINED MINIMIZED SET MINIMIZED=1 && START "" /MIN "%~dpnx0" %* && EXIT

SET TARGETPATH=C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test
IF NOT EXIST "%TARGETPATH%" GOTO :ERROR
%SYSTEMROOT%\EXPLORER /SELECT, "%TARGETPATH%"
GOTO :END

:ERROR
SET msgboxTitle=This is my Message Title
SET msgboxBody=This is my Message Body
SET tmpmsgbox=%temp%\~tmpmsgbox.vbs
IF EXIST "%tmpmsgbox%" DEL /F /Q "%tmpmsgbox%"
ECHO msgbox "%msgboxBody%",0,"%msgboxTitle%">"%tmpmsgbox%"
WSCRIPT "%tmpmsgbox%"

:END
```

But what if I wanted to do something like this?

```
SET msgboxTitle=>:C
SET msgboxBody=>:C
```

I already tried doing stuff like *">:C"* or *'>:C'*, but it just gives me a blank error message. Is there any way to do this?
Also, how do I edit the text in the **OK** button?

Comment: `SET "msgboxTitle=>:C"` and  `SET "msgboxBody=>:C"`  Always use quotes as a best practice regardless of trying to use special characters.

Comment: You cannot edit the text in the button.  That is clearly defined in the help for the msgbox function.  You have options 0 thru 5 to display different buttons.